# Move zip file between servers using C#

Tags: c#

I want to move the zip file from one server to another server.
What is the best way to do that using C#?

If i am on my local machine running my C# application.
And I want to access two servers server A and serverB using File.COpy() to transfer the file from A to B then it is giving me credential issue.

I don't know whether I have UNC share for both the servers.
I want to use webrequest to transfer the zip file from Server A to Server B from my machine.

Comment: Are the servers on the same network? Are they behind different firewalls? Are they both up and running at the same time? More information please?

Comment: like the file exist on server \\abc\\e$\\temp\\temp.zip and I want ot move to server \\def\\c$\\windows. And servers are up.

Answer (score 11):

If you have a UNC share on the destination server, you can just use

```
System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileLocation, 
                     String destinationFileLocation)
```

Comment: How can I check whether my destination server has UNC share or not?

Comment: In the Run dialog, type \\servername and see what shares are listed.  Command-line equivalent is net view \\servername.

Comment: When im trying to use the copy function im getting couldn't find part of the path for source file. But i can use the same path in cmd line to pen the folder.what could be the reason

Comment: If i don't have the UNC share on destination server then?

Answer (score 2):

Otherwise you have to simply FTP it.

http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/280.html